# Expression for the (1+1)-dimensional retarded Dirac propagator in position space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, dirac-equation, dirac-delta-distributions, propagator

Where an expression for the (1+1)-dimensional retarded Dirac propagator in position space can be found, especially including the generalized funcion supported on the light-cone?

In particular, is it true that the square of the absolute value of this distribution is ill-defined (hence cannot be interpreted as charge/probability density)?

An expression for the required propagator, i.e., the retarded fundamental solution of the Dirac equation in $(1+1)$-dimensions
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-m  & i\,\partial/\partial t-i\,\partial/\partial x \\
i\,\partial/\partial t+i\,\partial/\partial x & -m
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_1 \\ \psi_2
\end{pmatrix}=0
$$
inside the future light cone $t>|x|$ is (see e.g. Eq.~(13) in [this paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/17/2/023/meta))
$$
\frac{m}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{t+x}{\sqrt{t^2-x^2}}\,J_1(m\sqrt{t^2-x^2}) &
i\,J_0(m\sqrt{t^2-x^2}) \\
i\,J_0(m\sqrt{t^2-x^2}) & 
\frac{-t+x}{\sqrt{t^2-x^2}}\,J_1(m\sqrt{t^2-x^2})
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The propagator contains also some generalized function supported on the future light cone $t=|x|$, which particularly interested in. A receipt for computation has been given in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/98228/149880), but it seems tricky to identify all the resulting delta-functions and their derivatives (and also the retarded propagator has been confused with the Feynman propagator there). Thus a reference to the final expression would be preferrable.

Notice that searching for *retarded* Dirac propagator (vanishing outside the light cone), not just the 'Dirac propagator' or Feynman propagator (not vanishing outside the light cone).

Comment: If you have a retarded function, it is easy to obtain its advanced version by a simple variable change. Then you may construct the Feynman function, etc., and vice versa, no?

Comment: The retarded propagator indeed can be obtained from the Feynman propator. But expression for neither the retarded nor Feynman propagator (including the generalized function!) is known to me for 1+1-dimensions and spin 1/2.